# MySQL: Find rows in one table and not the other, find both

Tags: mysql, join

I'm struggling to get my head around MySQL joins. I have three tables

```
-- events
id  name
1   Event 1
2   Event 2

--  registrations
id   event  name
1    1      Alice
2    1      Bob
3    2      Alice
4    2      Charlie

-- scores
id  event  name     score
1   1      Alice    10
2   1      Charlie  20
3   2      Alice    15
4   2      Bob      30
```

For each event I'm trying to work out

- How many people registered (rows in registration table) but did NOT get a score (exclude rows in scores table)
- How many people got a score (rows in scores table) but did NOT register (exclude rows in registration table)
- How many people BOTH registered and got a score

I've tried different variations of

```
SELECT  *
FROM    registrations r
LEFT JOIN scores s
ON      r.event = s.event
WHERE   s.event IS NULL
AND r.event = 1
```

but I'm not sure what I should be joining on: `event` or `name` but neither are null and I never seem to get the correct numbers I'm looking for. The result at the end should be like

```
      name     reg_only score_only reg&score total 
event Event 1  1        1          1         3
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the table to your * statement? "select r.* from registrations r....." The problem might be that the event column is present in several of the involved tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below 3 queries in same sequence as you mentioned in your query-

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, COUNT(r.id) AS registered_user
FROM `events` AS e
INNER JOIN registrations AS r ON e.id=r.event 
LEFT JOIN scores AS s ON e.id = s.event
WHERE   s.event IS NULL;

SELECT e.id, e.name, COUNT(r.id) AS scored_user
FROM `events`scores AS e
INNER JOIN scores AS s ON e.id=s.event 
LEFT JOIN registrations AS r ON e.id = r.event
WHERE   r.event IS NULL;

SELECT e.id, e.name, COUNT(*) AS both_user
FROM `events` AS e
INNER JOIN registrations AS r ON e.id=r.event 
INNER JOIN scores AS s ON e.id = s.event;
```